# Jmeter extending a threadgroup to make it more like listener

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

Is it even possible to extend Thread group in jmeter that it will be both Thread group and listener i mean hat it will get data from samplers and probably save then into a file ?

Comment: Straight forward implementation of Controller doesn't deal with sampler result, it's responsible for "designed test tree", rather than "specific test execution result". But of course, when you are creating your own, you can hack it the way you want. Question is WHY?

Comment: Kindly make your question more clearer. I think you do not want to add listeners in your script as I got to know from your question For that you could run your script in non gui mode. In this approach, a result file (.jtl) file will be generated at the end of the test. You can open it later in any of the listener you want to.

Comment: I want to make a Component That will extend ThreadGroup that it will get sampleresults and send them to database or somewhere.